# Is "approximative reduction" general knowledge to physicists?

Tags: terminology, approximations

I came across this concept called ["approximative reduction"](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=&as_epq=approximative+reduction), about which there are some papers, e.g. in this collection called [Structure and Approximation in Physical Theories](http://books.google.fi/books/about/Structure_and_Approximation_in_Physical.html?id=UroCoQEACAAJ&redir_esc=y).

Very briefly, it considers the formalization of physical approximations in mathematical sense. That is, gives ideas about the mathematics of "approximation" itself.

I know physicists deal with some form of error analysis, but is the term "approximative reduction" known? Any idea how valid this theory (or the theory in the mentioned collection) is?

Are there similar concepts?

Comment: not to me, an average experimental physicist

Comment: "Approximation reducation" a term used by philosophers, not real physicists...

Answer (score 2):

I am a professor of theoretical physics (although with a doctorate in applied mathematics), and I had never heard of "approximative reduction" until just now.  Following the links in the question, I could get a vague idea of what it meant, but it is not something that I have ever studied or discussed with other scientists.  I would conclude that this topic is not well known at all among physicists.  It might be better known among applied mathematicians, but I wouldn't count on that either.